# Receiving different SqlException in Windows service to expected

Tags: c#, sql-server, windows-services, sqlexception

I'm having a very strange issue. I have windows service which is failing because of a SqlException: "String or binary data would be truncated." for an INSERT statement.

Now this is a fairly basic error to solve but it is not the true error. If I do a trace and run the query straight on the database - there is NO error. All of the data in WAY shorter than the restrictions on the database.

I eventually took out some of this required columns from the query hoping to generate a different error: "Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Type'"

I don't however get this error! I am still getting "String or binary data would be truncated."

I DO get this error if I run the query from the trace straight on the DB.

Does anyone have any ideas on what could be happening here? Thanks!

**Edit to add**
Here's the query that is supposed to give me the cannot insert value error. The other query is the same but with more parameters:

```
declare @p4 int
set @p4=60029550
exec sp_executesql N'EXECUTE ssl_GetTTDVersionCallSeq 1, @TTDVersionIDVal OUTPUT
INSERT INTO TTDVersion(Task,ID) VALUES (@P0,@TTDVersionIDVal)',N'@P0 int,@TTDVersionIDVal int output',@P0=200003762,@TTDVersionIDVal=@p4 output
select @p4
```

Comment: Could you put in the query you tried?

Comment: I can, it's a very basic insert statement though, it is done in a execute sql statement though which might have something??

Comment: Is the ID a primary key? Auto incremented or something?

Comment: Primary key, generated from another table that holds a value (REASONS). But quite a few columns can't be NULL.

Comment: is the SP breaking or the insert statement outside? Have you tried debugging?

Comment: I obtain that from the SQL profiler. That statement alone runs fine on the DB. However when called from the code "something" breaks and debugging gives me the "trucated" error - even though that's definitely not what is happening.

Comment: - Are you sure the column you think is giving the error is actually the one giving the error?
- It's not the data length that's the problem, it's the data type length. Maybe cast your data to a different type in C# before running the query?
- If you try to insert the same data into a new table with a massive column datatype, does the query work?

Comment: I'm 100% sure because 1. there are values bigger than the ones I want to insert in the db and 2 if I run the query straight on the DB it works. Since I got the query through the profiler it is definitely the one being run.
On top of that if I change the query to something that SHOULD give a different error I still get the same data truncated error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the cause of this error. It was not at all in the query posted above. There was a trigger on the table which set the LastUpdatedBy column.

Most of the users have a 4 char user name but the user that the service was being run as didn't. The column limit was 4.

**Avoid this issue:**

- Triggers can be problematic. They aren't immediately visible - sp_help 'table' doesn't even return them. If they error you can't even trace the query.

**What I should of tried earlier:**

- Running the query as the user. (I wanted to but it's an admin user and someone else was using it at the time.)
- Checking all columns info vs what was in them and what was in the query. Then to check how that info is getting there. In this case a default constraint probably would of given same issue.